# Creating a folder at build Electron

Tags: electron

I'm looking to make a folder outside of a portable electron build.

I'm thinking that creating the folder when the app starts will trigger permissions so I'm hoping to find a way to do it within the build process.

I'm using electron-build for packaging the app.

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Something like [extra-files](https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents#extrafiles) in your `package.json` for file/folder configuration at build?

Comment: More like creating a folder with mkdir. I've currently achieved this by stringing a new script that runs 'mkdir' at the right location after the build script finished. 

I was wondering if there's a way to create it using the electron-builder config.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at electron build hook: https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration#hooks

You might want to put some function such as `fs.mkdir` at [afterPack](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration#afterpack) hook (after pack electron app but before creating installer). Hope this help.